# How can I deal with NULL values in data table turning into missing XML elements when inserting in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005, datatable

I want to insert data using XML in SQL Server 2005. So I got one datatable from the BackEnd and I passed the DataTable as follows;

```
     DataSet dsItem = new DataSet();
     DTItem.TableName = "ItemDetails";  //DTItem is the DataTable I got from the BackEnd
     dsItem.Tables.Add(DTItem);
```

My problem is, If any column contains null value then the XML not taking that null column. For ex: Consider this is my DataTable

```
     JobOrderID             CustomerID
    ------------           ------------
       4
```

Here CustomerID is null. When I fix the Trace and View, the DataTable which shows empty instead of null.
So. When I pass the DataTable, the XML does not consider the Null column. It takes as follows

```
 <NewDataSet>
   <ItemDetails>
      <JobOrderID>4</JobOrderID>
   </ItemDetails>
 </NewDataSet>
```

It is not taking CustomerID, So the insertion is not working. Why the DataTable does not show the Null values in the Column fields and How to pass if the DataTable containing null value as a XML?
Please any suggestions.

Comment: What would you want in the XML? `<CustomerID />`? This is different than a `NULL`. In string terms, it would be `""`. For an integer, it would simply be invalid. Perhaps explore the problem from vantage point of the insertion logic, not the XML, as the XML is valid for the given data.

Comment: @Anthony: Ok. I want to insert the DataTable which contains null value to the Sql server table at a Single time. How to do this?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand your question but maybe checking out DBNull.Value would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem by assigning `-1` instead of `null`. I know this is not the right solution, but I solved using this method.