# Why DataTable not showing the NULL values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, null

I have one DataTable Which I gets from the BackEnd. But When I fix the BreakPoint and Visualize the DataTable, It does not show the NULL values. Why is it so?

In the BackEnd, My Table looks like below:

```
          CustID          JobID          Qty
        ----------       --------       ------
           1               NULL          100
           2                1            200
```

But in the FrontEnd, My DataTable looks like below:

```
           CustID          JobID          Qty
        ----------       --------       ------
           1                             100
           2                1            200
```

Why it is not showing the NULL Values? Is there any specific reason? How to show the DataTable as it is like in the BackEnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between null in Database and null in code, To refer or check for nulls arising from data from a Database we have [`DBNUll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and its not the same as `null`

Comment: While Converting this Datatable as an XML DataSet, It ignores the tag which has NULL values. So while inserting problem arise.

Comment: @thevan .Surprise Its your own post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387118/how-can-i-deal-with-null-values-in-data-table-turning-into-missing-xml-elements-w

Comment: Yes I Solved that problem Temporarily. But I could not follow the same in all the scenarios. I am trying But I couldn't find a solution for this.

Comment: @thevan Can't you replace the same in the query instead of the null value replace by `""`, I don't think there is any other way to handle it else you will have to iterate and build the xml

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7xhzw18f(v=VS.100).aspx) page

Basically you can customize the way `NULL` properties are displayed. Instead of `blank` you can set it to `NULL`

Comment: How to assign NULL in the Blank Spaces in the DataTable?